MaterialAlertDialog Popup won't adjust pan until top
I recently migrated an AlertDialog to a MaterialAlertDialog

(and improved the overall layout, e.g. using the native buttons
instead of custom buttons in the custom view of the dialog.)

Previously I set the custom view on the dialog,
and executed this code:
dialog.window?.apply {
            clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE)
            clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM)
            setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE)
        }
        editText.requestFocus()

and the dialog would pan up just fine all the way to the top of the screen if needed.
However, since I moved it to MaterialAlertDialog, even with
setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN or WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE)

it will only pan halway to the top and stop even though it does not yet have sufficient space.
Both dialogs used an identical Theme that inherits from
ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog

The results currently look like this on Samsung S10 (Background blurred), but the issue also appears on other devices that require more panning:

As you can see, there is still a significant space to the top that does not get used. I am certain that it is not caused by the toolbar on top, because it worked fine with the old dialog.
The popup seems to always stop at the same point latest: just slightly below the top of the tab bar.
Is there any idea what may be the cause?
I would understand if the popup didn't resize due to some issues with my custom layout but since I don't resize but just try to pan it, I'm at a loss to what's wrong.
EDIT:
I have reverse engineered the bug and determined that it is related to using MaterialAlertDialogBuilder instead of AlertDialog.Builder.
When using the old dialog popup (the one that still worked), as soon as I change it to MaterialAlertDialogBuilder, the bug appears.

So, looking into the code for MaterialAlertDialogBuilder, there is a function where the backgroundInset gets set based on alertDialogStyle. By default it is 24dp (as far as I could see).
So, defining a custom alertDialogLayout and removing topInset (and bottom, for symmetry) worked charms.
In your AlertDialogTheme define:
<item name="alertDialogStyle">@style/NoInsetStyle</item>

and then define NoInsetStyle, that inherits from the original theme:
<style name="NoInsetStyle" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="backgroundInsetTop">0dp</item>
        <item name="backgroundInsetBottom">0dp</item>
</style>

that way, the panning works again. However, I would still consider this a bug of the MaterialAlertDialog because panning should always take precedence over some background inset, so I'm going to produce a MVP and report the issue to google.
